# Observable from list of timetamps

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

If I have a list of objects that contains a timestamp - how can I make an observable that fire events at the relative time between the timestamps?

Eg. if I have three objects with timestamps 2014-01-01 10:30, 2014-01-01 10:45 and 2014-01-01 11:30, I want the first event to fire right away, then the next 15 minutes later, and the last one 45 minutes after that.

How can I speed up the process, so that 1 minute equals 1 second? So the first event would fire right away as before, but the next would come 15 seconds later instead of 15 minutes and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of ways to do this I'm sure, but here's a quick sample using Observable.Generate to schedule events at a particular time. It uses a list of events - but given it works with an iterator, you can easily adapt it to use another source:

```
void Main()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    var events = new List<Tuple<DateTime, string>> {
        Tuple.Create(now.AddSeconds(5), "A"),
        Tuple.Create(now.AddSeconds(10), "B"),
        Tuple.Create(now.AddSeconds(15), "C")
    };

    var eventSource = Observable.Generate(
        (IEnumerator<Tuple<DateTime,string>>)events.GetEnumerator(),
        s => s.MoveNext(),
        s => s,
        s => s.Current.Item2, // the data
        s => s.Current.Item1); // the timing

    eventSource.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);                       
}
```

This writes out "A", "B" and "C" and 5, 10 and 15 seconds after start-up.

To speed up time, you can put some logic around how the scheduled time is interpreted. Another way it to use the `HistoricalScheduler`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969829/advanceable-historical-stream-and-live-stream-in-rx/20975724#20975724) for some insight on that.

Comment: HistoricalScheduler sounds interesting. Never heard about that one before. Observable.Generate( ) also looks nice. Thanks!

Comment: This may not work if the dates are out of order. It ``may`` not pull the next one and schedule it before the previous one. Though I'm not sure. The code for Generate in the RX source is complex.

Comment: Yes, it expects events to be in order. I don't want to live in a world where the enumerator supplies them out of order though! That would be mental. If you need to check for it, you could easily enough - but it would smell like you are "doing it wrong (tm)" to me. Also, out of order events against a *running* scheduler could be problematic in all implementations here. Generate is actually nice precisely *because* it only schedules the next event on the completion of the preceding one, and therefore prevents scheduler starvation.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to merge an enumerable of observables like so

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTimeOffset,string>> timeStamps = ...;
IObservable<Tuple<DateTimeOffset,string>> eventStamps = timeStamps
    .Select(s => Observable.Timer(s.Item1).Select(e=>s))
    .Merge();
```

As per James World's answer, to speed or slow time, you can add the historical scheduler as a second argument to Timer. (Give him the points for that bit. I didn't know about that before I read his answer )

```
Observable.Timer(s.Item1, historicalScheduler)
```

If you are wondering why DateTimeOffset rather than DateTime look at [DateTime vs DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset)

The nice thing is that the code above works if timeStamps is either `IEnumerable` or `IObservable`. There is an overload of merge that works for either.

Comment: ...and if you really *really* care about the `DateTime` vs `DateTimeOffset` debate, look at [nodatime](http://nodatime.org/)