# Delay Observable by time span between second last and last

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Say I have an `Observable<LogEntry>`, where `LogEntry` has a property `TimeStamp` (among others of course). The `LogEntry`s are created by reading a logfile.

```
public IObservable<LogEntry> GetLogRecords()
{
    return Observable.Create<LogEntry>(
    (IObserver<LogEntry> observer) =>
    {
        var lines = File.ReadLines(this.filePath);
        var enumerator = lines.GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            string line = enumerator.Current;

            if (!line.StartsWith("#"))
            {
                var entry = new LogEntry(line);
                observer.OnNext(entry);
            }
        }

        observer.OnCompleted();
        return Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Unsubscribed"));

    });
}
```

That Observable will 'fire' as fast as the file is read.

What I want is to space (delay) the events by the time span between the second last and the last LogEntry.TimeStamp

eg. something along the line

```
var replayObs = GetLogEntries().Delay(calculatedTimeDiff);
```

Comment: Do you read the whole file each time something is written to the file? The performance will degrade pretty fast...

Comment: No, that's just for demo purpose. Before "tailing" a production log file, I want to test my stuff "offline", hence replaying an archived log file.

Comment: This is really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255205/observable-from-list-of-timetamps/22256800#22256800

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a regular enumerable over your log file events (which could be lazy or not as you desire), and then see [Observable from list of timetamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255205/observable-from-list-of-timetamps/22256800#22256800). This is practically a duplicate question so I have marked it as such.

Comment: And to think I forgot all about `Generate` even though it bit me before :/ I really have problems thinking with Reactive Extensions

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to combine observables and be explicit for all calls to do it. First let's say you logentry contains some time info. I will let you see how to calculate the delay till the next entry, but for now lets assume your logentry contains the delay directly. A good way to find his delay would be to take the logfile first entry as a relative starting point.

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public int delay { get; set; }
}

public static LogEntry readLogEntryFromLine(string line)
{
    return new LogEntry() {delay = Int32.Parse(line)};
}
```

We setup some data

```
var lines = new string[] {"0","1","1","2","3","7"};
// this would be the lines you read from the file

var logEntry1 = readLogEntryFromLine(lines[0]) ;
```

What you need to do is start by creating an observable pushing the first logentries you need (let's say in your case that you want one of them; adding a second one is easy, see the `Concat` signature)

```
var firstTwoLogEntries = 
    Observable.Concat(  Observable.Return(logEntry1));
```

Then for each new line in your file, you create a new LogEntry that you add to the observable with the expected delay:

```
var finalObservable = firstTwoLogEntries;
var delayOfLatestLogEntry = logEntry1.delay;

foreach (var line in lines.Skip(1)) // we skip the filrst logentry that is our reference
{
    var logEntry = readLogEntryFromLine(line);
    finalObservable = Observable.Concat(finalObservable, Observable.Return(logEntry).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delayOfLatestLogEntry)));
    delayOfLatestLogEntry = logEntry.delay;
}
```

Finally suscribe to your observable

```
finalObservable.Subscribe((le) => Console.WriteLine("log event at " + DateTime.Now + " - next one in " + le.delay + " seconds"));
```